# Solving the whole number equation $2x+5y=90$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification, diophantine-equations, linear-diophantine-equations

> $$2x + 5y = 90$$$x$ and $y$ are whole numbers. how many $(x,y)$ can this equation get?

I thought it like this;
\begin{align*}
2x & = 90-5y\\
x & = \frac{90-5y}{2}
\end{align*}

$x$ is a whole number so must be divisible by $2$. So I thought that by giving $y$ the values $\{ 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16 \}$ it can be divided by $2$.

There can be $9$ $(x,y)$'s.

If it is true, is there a better way to do it? And If not, where did I make the mistake?

Thanks!

Comment: Looks pretty good, except you can also have $y=18$.

Comment: Thanks Gerry. Yeah, I didn't think that one.

Comment: Do you also allow negative solutions? Then you will get more. I am not sure about the word "whole". I've never seen it in this context when talking english. Translating it back into German yields the word for integer.

Comment: @Simon: In English *whole number* is equivalent either to *positive integer* or to *non-negative integer*, depending on the person using it; alik is evidently using it in the latter sense. It’s not equivalent to *ganze Zahl*.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thanks for the clarification! I guess I never came across it since people tend to use the less ambiguous terms...nothing better than learning new vocabulary at 9 in the morning ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you did is correct, except that you stopped short: $y=18$ is also possible. You could also have rewritten the equation as $5y=90-2x$, so $$y=\frac{90-2x}5=18-\frac{2x}5\;.$$ This implies that $x$ must be a multiple of $5$, so you get $x=0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40$, and $45$.

You can reduce the work by noticing that in the equation $$x=\frac{90-5y}2=45-\frac{5y}2\;,$$ $x$ decreases when $y$ increases. The smallest permissible value of $y$ is of course $0$, and as you saw, $y$ must be even. With just a little more work we determine directly what the largest possible value of $y$ is, and then we don’t have to try values one by one. The smallest permissible value for $x$ is $0$, so we must have $$\begin{align*}&45-\frac{5y}2\ge 0\;,\\\\
&45\ge\frac{5y}2\;,\\\\
&5y\le90\;,\text{ and finally}\\\\
&y\le18\;.
\end{align*}$$

Thus, we know that $y$ can only be one of the numbers $0,2,4,\dots,16,18$.

Comment: Many thanks Brian.